# Delphi equivalent to Free Pascal's FPC define?

Tags: pascal, freepascal, lazarus, delphi

Is there a compiler define that tells if source code is compiled with delphi, in the sense of an equivalent to the FPC define in Free Pascal?

I am developing a unit that should be compatible with three Pascal compilers (Lazarus / Free Pascal, Delphi and winsoft PocketStudio). There are some differences among the compilers, therefore I would like to provide some critical parts of the code in a compiler-specific version.

For Free Pascal I can write

```
{$IFDEF FPC}
  DoSomething;
{$ENDIF}
```

but what is the equivalent for Delphi?

Comment: See documentation for [`predifined conditionals`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Conditional_compilation_(Delphi)#Predefined_Conditionals). DCC perhaps.

Comment: There's none for Delphi. Is there one for PocketStudio? If there is, you can use `{$IFNDEF FPC}', '{$IFNDEF POCKET_STUDIO}', '{$ELSE}{$DEFINE DELPHI}`.

Comment: @KenWhite: There is one for Delphi - `DCC` - but only in XE and later.

Comment: @Remy: I know, but the question has no version tags. There is none for Delphi in general.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `DCC` define was added to the Delphi compiler in XE2.  Prior to that, you had to use `{$IFDEF VERxxx}` statements to check for the presence of individual `VERxxx` defines for each version of Delphi, or an `{$IF DECLARED(CompilerVersion)}` statement for Delphi 6+.

Comment: Are you sure about XE, not XE2?

Comment: Just know that `{$IF}` was introduced in D6, so you can use `{$IFDEF CONDITIONALEXPRESSIONS}` if you need to support earlier versions.

Answer (score 2):

Documentation [`predefined conditionals`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Conditional_compilation_%28Delphi%29#Predefined_Conditionals) reveals that `DCC` is a predefined symbol that could be used to separate Delphi from other compilers.

Comment: Only in Delphi XE and later, as `DCC` did not exist prior to XE.

Comment: Thanks, but this should be solvable.

Comment: It is "solvable", just ugly unless PocketStudio has something that can be tested for so Delphi is a fallback when nothing else is detected.  Indy gets around this by manually defining `DCC` for every Delphi version prior to XE, that way it can always test for `DCC` when needed.

Comment: Dropping versions that don't $if defined() also helps tremendously in simplifying include files.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your hints.

Based on them I can now find out, if the code is compiled with Delphi or Free Pascal with  the following statements:

```
{$IFDEF VER80}   {Delphi 1}
{$DEFINE DELPHI}
  DoSomeSpecificStuff;
{$ENDIF}

{$IFDEF VER90}   {Delphi 2}
{$DEFINE DELPHI}
  DoSomeSpecificStuff;
{$ENDIF}

{$IFDEF VER100}   {Delphi 3}
{$DEFINE DELPHI}
  DoSomeSpecificStuff;
{$ENDIF}

{$IFDEF VER120}   {Delphi 4}
{$DEFINE DELPHI}
  DoSomeSpecificStuff;
{$ENDIF}

{$IFDEF VER130}   {Delphi 5}
{$DEFINE DELPHI}
  DoSomeSpecificStuff;
{$ENDIF}

{$IFDEF VER140}   {Delphi 6}
{$DEFINE DELPHI}
{  DoSomeSpecificStuff;
{$ENDIF}

{$IFDEF VER150}   {Delphi 7}
{$DEFINE DELPHI}
  DoSomeSpecificStuff;
{$ENDIF}

{$IFDEF VER160}   {Delphi 8}
{$DEFINE DELPHI}
  DoSomeSpecificStuff;
{$ENDIF}

{$IFDEF VER170}   {Delphi 9}
{$DEFINE DELPHI}
  DoSomeSpecificStuff;
{$ENDIF}

{$IFDEF VER180}   {Delphi 10}
{$DEFINE DELPHI}
  DoSomeSpecificStuff;
{$ENDIF}

{$IFDEF VER185}   {Delphi 11 - Spacely}
{$DEFINE DELPHI}
  DoSomeSpecificStuff;
{$ENDIF}

{$IFDEF VER190}   {Delphi 11 - Highlander and Delphi 12}
{$DEFINE DELPHI}
  DoSomeSpecificStuff;
{$ENDIF}

{$IFDEF VER200}   {Delphi 12}
{$DEFINE DELPHI}
  DoSomeSpecificStuff;
{$ENDIF}

{$IFDEF VER210}   {Delphi 2010}
{$DEFINE DELPHI}
  DoSomeSpecificStuff;
{$ENDIF}

{$IFDEF DCC}   {Delphi XE and newer versions}
{$DEFINE DELPHI}
  DoSomeSpecificStuff;
{$ENDIF}

{$IFDEF FPC]   {Lazarus and Free Pascal}
  DoSomeSpecificStuff;
{$ENDIF}
```

Comment: Introducing $if declared here for versions >=6 will reduce redundant parts of DoSpecificStuff, same as DCC

Comment: You are right, but this formulation provides a form of backwards-compatibility. Old Pascal compilers don't support more elaborate forms of {$IFDEF} constructs.